# Write a file that already exists

Tags: java, file

How to write a file that exists with `FileOutputStream` ? When i run two times this program, the second time `oos` and `fos` are null

```
 public class ReadFile {
    static FileOutputStream fos = null;
    static ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        File f = new File("file.tmp");
        if (f.exists()) {
            //How to retreive an old oos to can write on old file ?
            oos.writeObject("12345");
            oos.writeObject("Today");
        }
        else
        {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("file.tmp");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        }
        oos.close();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f,true));
```

if you want to append to the file

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to overrite the file, add the true argument to the File or File OutputStream  constructors

```
new FileOutputStream( new File("Filename.txt"), true );

Parameters:
name - the system-dependent file name
append - if true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `FileWriter` instead of `FileOutputStream`, if you plan to write plain text.

```
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfilename", true)));
    out.println("the text");
```

The second parameter (`true`) will tell to append to file.

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f, true));
```

In your code, you have `ObjectOutputStream oos = null;`, so `oos` is `null`. You need to initialize it. Like this:

```
public class ReadFile {
    static FileOutputStream fos = null;
    static ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        File f = new File("file.tmp");
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f, true));
        if (f.exists()) {
            //How to retreive an old oos to can write on old file ?
            oos.writeObject("12345");
            oos.writeObject("Today");
        }
        else
        {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        }
        oos.close();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create new `FileOutputStream` with second argument set to `true`

```
FileOutputStream d = new FileOutputStream(file, append);
```